# Trying to use a azure Test Plan api to add tester name in Test suite from power shell script

Tags: powershell, api, rest, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

```
$UpdateTesterNameUri = "https://dev.azure.com/MyOrg/MyProj/_apis/test/Plans/" + $Id + "/Suites/121221/points/" + $node + "?api-version=6.0"
Write-Output $UpdateTesterNameUri
 $testerNameBody = 
        @{
tester       = @{
    "displayName" = "Veeresh Kokkalla "
    }
}
$testerName = $testerNameBody | ConvertTo-Json
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $UpdateTesterNameUri -Headers $headers -Method Patch -Body $testerName  -ContentType 'application/json'
```

Getting following issue

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: tester","typeName":"System.ArgumentNullException, 
mscorlib","typeKey":"ArgumentNullException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}
At C:\Users\v-vkokkalla\Downloads\ReleaseTrain - Dailymveeresh.ps1:173 char:13
+             Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $UpdateTesterNameUri -Headers $hea ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

When I put debug it shows tester has values.

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket?

Answer (score 0):

From your PowerShell sample, you need to define the userID in the request body. Then you can update the tester of the test point.

Here is an PowerShell example:

```
$token = "PAT"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/org/project/_apis/testplan/Plans/TestPlanID/Suites/TestSuiteID/TestPoint?includePointDetails=true&returnIdentityRef=true&api-version=6.0"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$JSON = @"
[
  {
    "id":Testpointid,
    "tester":
      {
       "id":"userid",
       "displayName":"xx"
      }
   }
]
"@

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Patch  -ContentType application/json -Body $JSON

Write-Host "$response"
```